# Limit maximum image width on web broswer

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

What is the best practice to limit the maximum image width on the browser, with only HTML and CSS? I did a search on Google.com, and I didn’t find any good results. Thanks!

Also, I want to keep the proportion height ratio as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `style="max-width:NNNpx"` (or `max-height:NNNpx`) (you can use `%` as a measurement as well - e.g. `max-width:10%`)

Comment: I remember IE doesn't support this feature. Also, I want to keep the proportion height ration as well :)

Comment: `max-width` is supported in IE7+. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530811.aspx

Comment: Check out this article on getting older versions of IE to play well with max-width:  http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/

Comment: If you specify only max-width or max-height - the ratio is preserved. For IE see a comment above from Ryan

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the width of images using CSS:

```
img.limit-width {
    max-width:50%;
}
```

You can use `px` and `em` in addition to a percentage as well.